# The class is added to the HTML element, but the CSS rules are not applied at all. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[Complete SSCCE JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/w7eowzcq/1/)**

I have some JQuery code to add a CSS `class` (by the name of `sticky`) and an inline style (`top` location offset) to a `nav` element (`.header-menu-container-nav`) when the page is scrolled to the extent that the `scrollTop` (the distance traversed while scrolling) becomes greater than the `height` of the `viewport`.

**The problem is** that when I test it and see what is happening in the firefox inspector,

1. **The class `sticky` does seem to be added in the `nav` element's
   `class` attribute in the HTML, but it does not seem to be applied in
   the CSS (does not show in the CSS part of the firefox inspector).**
2. **The inline attribute `top` is not added at all.**

[image]

***So can somebody point out why this might be happening, and how can I solve this?***

The JQuery following code is used:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var vph = $(window).height();

    //alert("Viewport Height:"+vph+"\nDocument Height:" + $(document).height()); //check

    var originalHeaderPosition =  $(".header-menu-container-nav").offset().top;

    //alert("OriginalHeaderPosition: "+originalHeaderPosition); //check

    var currentHeaderPosition = $(document).scrollTop();

    var deltaHeaderPosition = currentHeaderPosition - originalHeaderPosition;

    //alert("deltaHeaderPosition: "+ deltaHeaderPosition);

    if (deltaHeaderPosition >= vph) {
        //alert("Condition met!"); //check

        $('.header-menu-container-nav').addClass('sticky');

        $('.header-menu-container-nav').css('top',(deltaMenuPosition)+'px');

        $('.header-menu-container-nav').fadeIn()
    }
});
```

Comment: Check if class sticky exists in your CSS file and also whats `deltaMenuPosition`?

Comment: Not that it might be what you're looking for but you're missing a comma after your fadeIn(), at least in your extract here.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Thank you, I was completely unaware of this. I use tags in the titles for the same reason they have mentioned in the question you linked. I'll take care of this in future. Now i request you to not go and downvote all my questions, i will try to edit my past questions if you think there is an utmost need to do so.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Removed tags from many questions of mine. i will do more as I get time.

Comment: @Zarah I would never downvote because of things I can edit - And, editing silently doesn't give any learning curve :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I agree, but giving a sort of warning in the form of comment would do too, and then if I did it again, you could have downvoted. That would have been more nice of you =)

Comment: @Zarah once again: I **did not** downvote any of your questions - I just added a comment, did some edit, and that was all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write proper hierarchy.

Use

```
.header-menu-container-nav.sticky {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}
```

instead of

```
.header-menu-container-nav .sticky {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the JSFiddle with your alerts and your condition just never fires. Check your calculations. `originalHeaderPosition` is always 0 and `deltaHeaderPosition` is always lower than `vph`